# How can I do to display all the name?

Tags: html, django, select, django-models

Hello I would like to create a select using Django I have a model :

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, default=None)
```

And I would like to create a select with option of name from the table Test.

How can I do this ?

I tried this :

```
<select class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                {{  for name in Test }}
                    <option value="{{ name.id }}">{{ name.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

But it does not work...

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

just change `{{  for name in Test }}` to `{{  for name in Test.all }}`

Comment: check the name that you pass data to template sometimes its just the wrong name

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to pass the list of `Test` using the context.

**app/view.py**

```py
def my_view(request):
    context = {
        tests: Test.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'my_html_with_the_select.html', context)
```

**app/templates/my_html_with_the_select.html**

```html
<select class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for test in tests %}
        <option value="{{ test.id }}">{{ test.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```